# Most general first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How is $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$ is the most general first order ordinary differential equation ? isn't $f(x,y(x),y'(x))=0$ the most general first order ODE ? I mean isn't a restriction to single out $y'(x)$ from $f$ ? thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the implicit form is more general. However, either one can isolate the first derivatives to the explicit form or the equation is not an ODE but an DAE (differential-algebraic equations) of positive index.

So in treating ODE theory it is sufficient and, via the Picard integral equation, also more expedient to treat the explicit form.

Comment: I don't work in the field, but I'd never heard of this distinction before; I thought every equation involving derivatives of a function of one variable was an ODE.  What is the actual definition of an ODE, and where can I find it in the literature?

Answer (score 0):

Depends, if you mean firs order and first degree differential equations then the first form with explicit y' is most general. The second form allows multiple degrees.